# How to get a $\mathcal{N}=2$ SuperYang-Mills Lagrangian from a quiver

Tags: string-theory, research-level, supersymmetry, gauge-theory, yang-mills

How can one write down the $\mathcal{N}=2$ SuperYang-Mills Lagrangian given a quiver graph?

For concreteness consider the quiver

$$(2)-(4)-[6]$$

where the node $(2)$ corresponds to a $U(2)$ factor of the gauge group, the $(4)$ node is a $U(4)$ factor and the $[6]$ node is a $SU(6)$ global symmetry (flavour).
The lines correspond to two $\mathcal{N}=2$ hypermultiplets charged in the fundamental representations of one node and the antifundamental representation of the other node into which the line ends.

In particular, how can one read the superpotential from this graph?
How can one read the Kahler potential? Is this latter one always assumed to be canonical?

In case you would like to choose an easier quiver to make an easier example it is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Qmechanic how do I know if a new tag is useful or not?
I thought that inserting the tag "quiver-gauge-theory" would have been a good thing, since it is the tag that fits the best this kind of problem.
Furthermore, I absolutely can not understand why you eliminated the tag "string-theory". Problems of quiver-gauge-theory such as this one arise in a natural way from considering gauge theories living on brane-systems. Which is, indeed, string theory, and probably who knows best this kind of topic is follwing the "sting-theory" tag.

Comment: Well, do what you think is best. I'm just trying to avoid the analogue of the Kessler syndrome for tags :) E.g. note that it currently is possible to easily search for [quiver](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=quiver) even without a quiver tag.

Comment: Yes you are right. I haven't thought about that. Probably it is best not to create a tag until there are quite a number of questions on that specific topic.
I re-added string-theory by the way. =)

Comment: Btw. in which references are you reading about quiver theories?

Comment: It is hard to find pedagogical references, since the topic is pretty new (late nineties) and no one has written review or introductory articles yet.

The first (and main) paper is this http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9603167

Also this is a good introduction http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.4474

However now I am working on some papers written by my supervisor, on "combinatorial" methods to compute the moduli space of a certain class of Quiver gauge theories.

An amazing example of these methods is this one http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.2657

Answer (score 2):

A quiver is a neat way of representing the field content of a large class of supersymmetric field theories. One also needs to specify the amount of supersymmetry to understand what a node or an edge stands for.

$\mathcal{N}=2$ supersymmetry implies that that the complete action can be written in terms of a holomorphic function which simultaneously determines both the Kahler and superpotential. The quiver doesn't give you this holomorphic function. With some assumptions on the form of the action in a derivative expansion, you can write out the function.

The simplest examples are those studied by Seiberg and Witten (arXiv:hep-th/9407087 and arXiv:hep-th/9408099) and in my opinion, the best starting point from a pedagogical viewpoint. The first paper discuss the case of a single node i.e., the quiver (2) and the second paper discusses the quiver $(2)-[N_f]$ for $N_f=1,2,3,4$.

Comment: Which is this holomorphic function you are referring to?
I believed that the superpotential in $\mathcal{N}=2$ was fixed, and could be read directly from the quiver.

Comment: See the first paper by Seiberg and Witten for details about the holomorphic function. Another more general reference is a talk by Seiberg http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9408013 -- section 4 is on N=2 theories.

Comment: Yes, the superpotential can be fixed if you make assumptions about the kinetic term for the fields.

Comment: Hold on... From recent reading I found out that in any $\mathcal{N}=2$ lagrangian the superpotential is identically 0.
Isn't it?
What do you mean with "the superpotential can be fixed if you make assumptions about the kinetic term for the fields"?
It seems to me that the holomorphic function you refer to, namely the "prepotential" fixes the kahler metric and the scalar potential, but there is no superpotential at all.
Am I wrong?

Comment: Terms like superpotential and Kahler potential are $\mathcal{N}=1$ terminology. Yes, the holomorphic function for $\mathcal{N}=2$ susy Lagrangians is called the prepotential. Here is an example where you know the superpotential is **not** zero. You can think of $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM as a $\mathcal{N}=2$ theory with a vector multiplet(with N=1 chiral $\Phi$) and an adjoint hypermultiplet, (N=1 chirals $Q$ and $\tilde{Q}$). There is a cubic superpotential: $\tilde{Q}\Phi Q$. However, for a theory with only vector multiplets, a superpotential does not exist.

Comment: Must read for understanding extended supersymmetry is the review by Sohnius: Physics Reports 128 (1985)39-204.